# Which is the best way to making Bundling in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the best way to make Bundling using AP.NET MVC?

1. Per file (bundle all the files which require on .cshtml)
2. Per the JS file group (bundle all the jQuery files and then include in the .cshtml)

And why should I go for that specific option?

Comment: Define "best". It depends on various factors such as the number of files, the number of bundles you intend to create and the total file size.

Answer (score 0):

I would say per group, but it depends on how you group your files.

You can group bundles per module/components.

- The ubiquitous jQuery gets its own bundle and referenced in the layout page.
- Components or libraries that depends on jQuery gets their own bundle, referencing them is tricky.

  1. You can reference them on specific pages that only require them, which can improve performance.
  2. You can reference them on the layout page, which can save you trouble of referencing to individual pages.
  3. I usually promote components into the layout page once they start occupying more than enough pages (40% is a good estimate)
- Individual CSS themes gets the same treatment, however, I usually break up parts of my CSS into their separate files that are only specific to certain pages.

Here is a sample:

```
// jQuery
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

// jQuery Bootstrap
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-style").Include(
            "~/Content/Styles/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/Styles/bootstrap-custom.css"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-script").Include(
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

// Boostrap DateTime Picker Component
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-datetimepicker-style").Include(
            "~/Content/Styles/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-datetimepicker-script").Include(
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"));
```

Comment: @VinodBhoite - Thanks, you can show your appreciation by accepting my answer if it solves to your problem.